# Cannot use SORTED for a list

Tags: list, sorting, typeerror

The error occurs in the last step of this code when I try to sort a list using SORTED. I get the error message that a "list object is not callable". I want to use the SORTED and not the SORT function for this.

```
from csv import reader
import datetime as dt
open_file = open("hacker_news.csv")
read_file = reader(open_file)
hn = list(read_file)
headers = hn[0]
hn = hn[1:]
def explore_data(dataset,start,finish,col_rows=True):

    dataset_slice = dataset[start:finish]
    for row in dataset_slice:
        print(row)
        print('\n')

    if col_rows:
        print('rows:' , len(dataset))
        print('columns:' , len(dataset[0]))
    
ask_posts = []
show_posts = []
other_posts = []

for row in hn:
    title = row[1]
    if title.lower().startswith("ask hn"):
        ask_posts.append(row)
    elif title.lower().startswith("show hn"):
        show_posts.append(row)
    else:
        other_posts.append(row)


total_ask_comments = 0
total_show_comments = 0
total = 0

for row in ask_posts:
    total += 1
    num_comments = int(row[4])
    total_ask_comments += num_comments

avg_ask_comments = total_ask_comments/total
print(avg_ask_comments)

for row in show_posts:
    total += 1
    num_comments = int(row[4])
    total_show_comments += num_comments
    
avg_show_comments = total_show_comments/total
print(avg_show_comments)
    
result_list = []

for row in ask_posts:
    created_at = row[6]
    num_comments = int(row[4])
    result_list.append([created_at,num_comments])

counts_by_hour = {}
comments_by_hour = {}

for row in result_list:
        comment = row[1]
        date_time = row[0]
        date_time = dt.datetime.strptime(date_time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
        hour = date_time.strftime('%H')
        if hour not in counts_by_hour:
            counts_by_hour[hour] = 1
            comments_by_hour[hour] = comment
        else:
            counts_by_hour[hour] += 1
            comments_by_hour[hour] += comment

              
for hour in counts_by_hour:
    if hour in comments_by_hour:
        avg = round(comments_by_hour[hour]/counts_by_hour[hour],2)
        avg_by_hour.append([hour,avg])
for row in avg_by_hour:
    swap_avg_by_hour.append([row[1], row[0]])
    
print(swap_avg_by_hour)

sorted_swap = sorted(swap_avg_by_hour, reverse=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-307863a4b1cd> in <module>
      6 print(swap_avg_by_hour)
      7 
----> 8 sorted_swap = sorted(swap_avg_by_hour, reverse=True)
      9 
     10 print(sorted_swap)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Not sure how to upload the csv as don't see an upload option. Is there an obvious error in the code? or can someone help with instructions to upload the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare these 2 lists before appnding  `avg_by_hour = [] swap_avg_by_hour= []`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look :) I declared the two but the type error for list ["list object is not callable"] still remains. Do you notice anything else that could be the problem?

Comment: add the value of list swap_avg_by_hour to the question